# Can I download my iOS App Store Icon from my iTunesConnect account?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Can I download the 1024x1024 App Store Icon from my iTunesConnect account portal?

The icon in the portal says "This icon will be used on the App Store. For apps built with Xcode 9 or later, add this icon in the build. For apps built with earlier versions of Xcode, add the icon here."

I'm using XCode 9 now but I lost the original file. I can't find a way to download my icon from the portal.

Comment: I got the icon so I'm good now, but an answer for this might save someone else some heartache...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No direct way to download the app icon, but possible with the developer tools of any browser.

- Log into https://itunesconnect.apple.com and choose your app.
- Right click on the app icon under "General App Information" > App Store Icon and Inspect / View source with the developer tools of Chrome/Safari/Firefox
- Find the `<img>` tag.

[image]

- Get the URL (both `src`or `ng-src` work. URL should look something like this:

  > https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple111/v4/eb/d7/18/ebd71843-0f6e-b78c-aa66-8b6c9b4e79e9/mzl.lhnaxkoi.png/150x150bb.jpg
- Remove the last part: 150x150bb and replace it by 1024x1024

  > https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple111/v4/eb/d7/18/ebd71843-0f6e-b78c-aa66-8b6c9b4e79e9/mzl.lhnaxkoi.png/1024x1024.jpg

Voila, you got the icon.

Comment: @max This gives icon with a white background. Any chance I can find the same icon with transparent background?

Comment: Apple doesn't accept transparent icons in the first place. You should, generally speaking, don't crop icons or use transparencies.

Comment: The problem with this is that is upscaled. So technically it is 1024x1024, but it weights much more than it should and has jpg artefacts. If there's an option, try to export the image from it's original source.

Answer (score 0):

Just use developer tool on your browser and get jpg and png format like the picture.

[image]